# How to evaluate a multi-line block in ruby-debug console

Tags: ruby, debugging, ruby-debug

I would like to evaluate

```ruby
def foo
  puts "you done got fooed"
end
```

in the `ruby-debug` console.  It works fine fine with `irb`.  But in
ruby-debug, I can't get the reader to continue reading input after a newline.

I've even tried ending the line in a backslash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can enter irb from rdebug:

```
(rdb:1) irb
irb(main):001:0> self
=> main
irb(main):002:0> def foo
irb(main):003:1> puts "foo!"
irb(main):004:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> exit
(rdb:1) p foo
foo!
nil
(rdb:1)
```